# Can I make direct payment from one of my PayPal account to another PayPal account on single button click?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

When I click on one button some of amount from my one PayPal account i need to transfer in another PayPal account without going over to a PayPal page.

Requirement is like when any user buys product payment will go into admin account and on some specific time admin will send payment to vendors so for that I need to make payment on only single click from admin's account to vendor's account.

Is this possible?

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? [What research have you done](https://www.google.com/search?q=paypal+API+send+payment)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible if the sending account is approved for PayPal Payouts

[See here for the integration guide and prerequisites](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts), and how to request access to Payouts

Comment: Thank you so much @Preston. Your answer helped me a lot. I did PayPal Payout Integration and that's what I wanted. :)